# How can i select the 3rd the same element as others inside another element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code and i wan't to select the 3rd element inside it:

```
<body>
    <div>First element</div>
    <div>Second element</div>
    <div>Third element</div>
</body>
```

How can i do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you go. This is one of the way to do that.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var thirdDiv = $("div").eq(2);
   console.log(thirdDiv);    
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here : http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

basically if you do something like this :
$("div:nth-child(3)").append(" - 3nd!");

Comment: This works fine, but it's better in most cases to use `$.eq()`. It's faster becuase `nth-child()` doesn't have to be parsed out of the selector string, and it's easier to use variables with `$.eq()` as no string concatenation is needed.